# Nicescroll not displaying for Ajax load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, nicescroll

I've tried looking everywhere for an answer to this. My issue is a bit different from what I've seen here regarding the AJAX load and nicescroll plugin. Nicescroll is currently not working for my html page that is triggered to display over on top of my main page when I click on a link on the main page by an AJAX trigger. It's not a div changing content, it's a completely new page that slides in, so I'm not sure if this is will be a bit more complicated to fix.

I've tried using the code below in my main page but it doesn't work

```
$('.cbp-item').click(function(){
  $('.cbp-popup-wrap').getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if element .cbp-item is added to the page dynamically you will have to bind the click event by using "live"

```js
$('.cbp-item').live("click",function(){
  $('.cbp-popup-wrap').getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

or "on"